# Save numerical values with "%" symbol as float in Excel - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have been using `openpyxl` to make changes to column size and datatypes and structure the overall thing in Excel. However, I have a few percentage values which are stored in string format:

[image]

However, when I double click on the cell value it automatically gets converted into numerical format, but the "%" symbol is retained like this:

[image]

I am using the following piece of code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles.numbers import FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = path) 
worksheet = wb.active
string_check= re.compile('%')
if (string_check.search(cell.value) != None):
   cell.number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
wb.save(filename = path)
```

But when I open back the Excel file, I see the issue still persists. The comment with the yellow exclamation mark still appears and on double-clicking the cell it goes away, i.e. the numerical value with the "%" symbol stays but in float format. How can I make sure that Python is able to save the excel file with the numerical values with "%" symbol in float format?

Comment: What are the values of the cell? It sounds like they are text and not the actual numbers based on the comment. I click on them and the format changes. If it is text you’ll need to add some post processing in pandas, like `df[col].str.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(‘%’))/100 if x.find(‘%’) else float(x))`

Comment: When i double click the values get converted to float format but the % symbol remains. But when I try to do it in python, as you can see in the piece of code it exports back as text only. I habe tried `{:.%}.format(cell_value)` as well. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I misread your question. It makes sense now. You are going from df to excel not the other way around!

Comment: Yeah, here I am using `openpyxl` though to open the workbook and make the formatting, etc.

Comment: Format and the underlying value are separate. Changing the format doesn't change the underlying value. Applying percentage formatting doesn't change the text to an actual number/float.